# Which NTLM version (1 or 2) does SMBJ authenticator support?

Tags: java, ntlm, ntlmv2, smbj

I am developing an application which needs to access a network share using SMB. I was told that if security detects an authentication attempt using NTLM v. 1, then the respective firewall rules will be revoked.

Therefore I need to make sure that [SMBJ](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj) (which I may use for this) supports NTLM v. 2 and uses it by default.

Does SMBJ support NTLM v. 2? Does it use it by default?

**My own attempts at finding out**

In the [source code](https://github.com/hierynomus/smbj/blob/master/src/main/java/com/hierynomus/smbj/auth/NtlmAuthenticator.java) of SMBJ I found following fragment:

```
byte[] serverChallenge = challenge.getServerChallenge();
byte[] responseKeyNT = ntlmFunctions.NTOWFv2(String.valueOf(context.getPassword()), context.getUsername(), context.getDomain());
byte[] ntlmv2ClientChallenge = ntlmFunctions.(challenge.getTargetInfo());
byte[] ntlmv2Response = ntlmFunctions.getNTLMv2Response(responseKeyNT, serverChallenge, ntlmv2ClientChallenge);
```

The names `getNTLMv2ClientChallenge` and `getNTLMv2Response` suggest that NTLM v. 2 may be used.

Also, JCIFS homepage [claims](https://www.jcifs.org/) that SMBJ is a successor project:

> Fortunately there are multiple new open source SMB Java projects to try including the following:
>
> jcifs-codelibs
> jcifs-ng
> smbj

According to its [FAQ](https://www.jcifs.org/src/docs/faq.html#ntlmv2), JCIFS has been using NTLM v. 2 since version 1.3.0.

If

1. JCIFS supports NTLM v. 2 and uses it by default,
2. SMBJ is based on JCIFS,

then SMBJ should support NTLM v. 2 and use it by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, SMBJ uses either NTLMv2 or SPNEGO for authentication. You can configure which one you want to use. It doesn't use NTLMv1.